# Identifying global variable assignments

Tags: c, doxygen

Is there a way to locate all the functions that assign to a specific global variable ?

For example, In one `.c` file are all my globals :

```
int x;
```

I would like to know which functions this variable `x` is being assigned in:

```
void temp(void) {
    x = 1;
}
```

Here `x` is assigned in the function `temp`.

Comment: Why any  specific task ?

Comment: To calculate the RAM usage of each function.

Comment: What about more complex assignments (e.g. via dereferencing a pointer)?  What does this have to do with Doxygen?

Comment: There are no more complex assignments just simple ones.  Doxygen can show you all the variables used in a function but I only want the variables that are assigned in the function.

Comment: compile/link the program using the -ggdb parameter,  Use gdb to run the program (the interactive wrapper ddd is also good)  set up a breakpoint for write to the variable.  each time the breakpoint is hit, perform a backtrace 'bt' to find out which function accessed that variable,  similar results can be obtained with most debuggers (including gdb) by writing a macro to handle the sequencing of commands to the debugger

Comment: Sorry, but how exactly this information will help to identify the RAM usage?

Comment: A very naive solution could be to comment the variable declaration and let the compiler complain. You should be able to recover the function names. I don't know if there would be corner cases though.

Comment: @user5572685 Well, if this is the kind of solution that the OP is looking for, the properly formatted `grep` will do that as well..

Comment: Or just use an IDE with "find references" option, such as an Eclipse.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes it will. You have just to properly handle strings literals and comments.